# AppSettings value is returning null in ternary operator

Tags: c#

I've been moving some of my string values into my web config, however, one value is returning null when used as a condition in a ternary operator.

Web Config:

```
<add key="Main.Root" value="www.blah.com" />
```

AppSettings.cs:

```
public struct SiteRoots
{
   public static readonly string Test = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Main.Root"];
}
```

Code:

```
 ViewBag.Profile = HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled || HttpContext.Request.Url.Host == AppSettings.SiteRoots.Test ? AppSettings.GTMKeys.Test : AppSettings.GTMKeys.Live;
```

If I use "AppSettings.SiteRoots.Test" anywhere else on the page, it returns the correct value, it only seems to return null when used as a condition inside the ternary operator.

Comment: If you think that the ternary operator is the problem then just convert it into an if-else statement and see if it disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the `ternary` expression in paraenthesis, also ensure `AppSettings.GTMKeys.Test` and `AppSettings.GTMKeys.Live` gives `boolean` to that it could be used with `||`.

```
ViewBag.Profile = HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled || (HttpContext.Request.Url.Host == AppSettings.SiteRoots.Test ? AppSettings.GTMKeys.Test : AppSettings.GTMKeys.Live);
```

You probably do not need HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled in your expression

```
ViewBag.Profile = HttpContext.Request.Url.Host == AppSettings.SiteRoots.Test ? AppSettings.GTMKeys.Test : AppSettings.GTMKeys.Live;
```

Comment: Wasn't his intention rather `ViewBag.Profile = (...) ? Test : Live`?